# Flask - Not returning function result

Tags: python, flask

Looking for help with Flask App. I have code below, which renders page and asks user to provide "az_tenant" from a dropdown. Which is then passed in to an imported function "az_auth".

```
    from app.scripts.ms_azure.ms_azure_resource_list import az_auth


    ms_azure_resources = Blueprint("ms_azure_resources", __name__)


    @ms_azure_resources.route("/azure_resources", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def ms_azure_resources_list():
        title = "Microsoft Azure - Resources"
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("public_cloud/ms_azure_resources.html", title=title)

        if request.method == "POST":
            az_tenant = request.form.get("tenant_id")
            resources = az_auth(az_tenant)
            return render_template("public_cloud/ms_azure_resources.html", title=title, resources=resources)
```

Problem is, "az_auth" does some stuff and passes information along to another function to return result back to Flask app which is not happening.

```
def do_stuff(more_stuff):
    return result

def az_auth(TENANT_ID):
    do_stuff(more_stuff)
```

Whatever is happening inside of "az_auth" does return but not from functions that it's trying to run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `az_auth` method to following:

```py
def az_auth(TENANT_ID):
    return do_stuff(more_stuff)
```

Problem is you are ot returning anything from `az_auth` method.